# Laravel Update Required all Inputs to be filled out before Saving to Database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I am new to laravel, I need to Update Contents but my problem is even though I dont want to update the image the program force me to.. what should i need to do?

What I want is to Update the form without requiring any fields.. because what I currently have here is the program requires me to input all the fields

> My **Controller**

```
 $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'about_image' => ''
    ]);

    if ($request->has('about_image'))
    {   
        //Handle File Upload

        $about = [];
        foreach ($request->file('about_image') as $key => $file)
        {
            // Get FileName
            $filenameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            //Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo( $filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            //Get just extension
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //Filename to Store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //Upload Image
            $path = $file->storeAs('public/about_images',$fileNameToStore);
            array_push($about, $fileNameToStore);
        }

        $fileNameToStore = serialize($about);
    }
    else
    {
        $fileNameToStore='noimage.jpg';
    }

    foreach ($about as $key => $value) {
        $aboutContent =  About::find($id);

        $aboutContent->title = $request->title[$key];

        $aboutContent->description = $request->description[$key];     

        if($request->hasFile('about_image')){
        $aboutContent->about_image = $value;    
        }

        $aboutContent->save();
    }
    return redirect('/admin/airlineplus/aboutus')->with('success', 'Content Created');
```

> My **View**

```
 {!! Form::open(['action'=>['Admin\AboutusController@update', $about->id], 'method' => 'POST','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data', 'name' => 'add_name', 'id' => 'add_name']) !!}
<div class="form-group">   
    <div class="table-responsive">  
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
           <tr>  
              <td>  {{Form::text('title[]', $about->title, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter a Title'])}}<br>
                    {{Form::textarea('description[]', $about->description, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter a Description'])}} <br>

                          {{ Form::file('about_image[]') }} <b>{{ $about->about_image }}</b>


              </td>
              <td>{{ Form::button('', ['class' => 'btn btn-success fa fa-plus-circle', 'id'=>'add','name'=>'add', 'style'=>'font-size:15px;']) }}</td>
           </tr>  
        </table>  
        {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
        {{Form::submit('submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary', 'name'=>'submit'])}}
    </div> 
</div>  
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Try to remove `'about_image' => ''` from `$this->validate($request, [` .

Comment: it has an error , the error says,  Undefined variable: about

Comment: Are you passing `about_image` in the `request`? Check if it goes to `if ($request->has('about_image'))
    {  `. And are you using `about` variable in your blade file?

Comment: Hey dude, the error is pointing the foreach loop i think the foreachloop about is the problem do you have any solution to that?

Comment: yes problem is foreach loop

Comment: Did you pass `about_image` while edit form? As your question is about `I dont want to update the image the program force me to`!!

Comment: Also, you are using `foreach ($about as $key => $value) {` remove `$about` as its not defined in it and you defined in `if ($request->has('about_image'))`. Hope you got it!

Comment: There ya go sir, I edited the form

Comment: All are working fine except for the about_image .. cause that is a button file.. then when I update the form.. it does not allow me to update without inserting new image again

Comment: What `'id'=>'add'` do in `form`? Is there any jQuery validation?

Comment: I have an array so when I insert button it is dynamically it has an ajax

Answer (score 0):

If You want to Update the form without requiring any fields remove

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'about_image' => ''
    ]);
```

from controller

```
if (!empty($about)) {
            foreach ($about as $key => $value) {
                $aboutContent = About::find($id);
                $aboutContent->title = $request->title[$key];
                $aboutContent->description = $request->description[$key];
                if ($request->hasFile('about_image')) {
                    $aboutContent->about_image = $value;
                }
                $aboutContent->save();
            }
        } else {
            $aboutContent = About::find($id);
            $aboutContent->title = $request->title[$key];
            $aboutContent->description = $request->description[$key];
            $aboutContent->save();
        }
```

Comment: it as an error here is the error ... Undefined variable: about

Comment: can you explain exactly what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the about_image entry on the validator, then just check it inside the Update method if it is not empty, like so:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->custom_rules(), $this->custom_messages());

 if ($validator->fails()){
   return redirect()->route('route_name', $id)->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
 }

 if ($file = $request->file('about_image')){
   $aboutContent->about_image = $file;   
 }
}



private function custom_rules()
{
  $rules = [ 
     'title' => 'required',
     'description' => 'required'
  ];
}

public function custom_messages()
{
  return $messages = [
     'title.required' => 'Title is required.',
     'description.required' => 'Description is required'
  ];
}
```